# how to convert a NString into binary string in IOS

Tags: ios, binary

I have an app developed in xCode which generates something like this:

```
98,112,108,105,115,116,48,48,-44,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4...
```

it is a NSMutableString representing a binary array...

but I want something like this:

```
010010101101011101
```

how do I do this???

Comment: Write software.  I'd suggest starting with a loop and some mask and shift operations.

Comment: (It would help if you at least told us if you want a "binary array" as in `bool[]` or as in the printable characters "01001...", or something else.)

Comment: I want that string 011001000010101 because I want to send it for a BLOB field in a ORACLE DB, currently I'm sending this 48,-44,0,1,0,2 and when I want it back from DB I get this:
48440102 is the same thing but without commas and - signs, then someone suggested me to send it as binary

Comment: For a SQL BLOB field you should send/receive the data as "pure binary" data, which is to say NSData.  Converting it to graphic character form simply reduces the efficiency of computation, transmission, and storage.  If you do not have a convenient way to transmit "pure binary" then use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which is about 2/3rds as compact, and which is a standard format.

Comment: (It's important to understand the difference between a pure *number* and the human-readable graphic presentation of a number.)

Answer (score 1):

This will transform your array into a string of 0's and 1's :

```
    NSMutableArray *array = ....
    NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:array
                                                              format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:NULL];

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how the above bears the slightest relationship to the OP's question.

Comment: I tried with your code by adding this to your example:
NSMutableString *cadena = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hola"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:cadena];

and if I use this: NSLog(@"cadena: %@", myString); I get this
cadena: (null) :/

Comment: Do you NSLog after the conversion into data ?

Comment: Yes, the result was      cadena: (null)

Comment: Is 'data' empty ? Try to follow step by step with the debugger and locate where the issue appears.

Comment: data is not empty, but when I turn into String, the string stills empty look, if I NSLog this:  NSLog(@"cadena: %@, my data: %@ datalength: %i", myString, data , data.length); this is my result: cadena: (null), my data: <62706c69 73743030 a2010154 686f6c61 080b0000 00000000 01010000 00000000 00020000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0010>, datalengh: 50

Comment: Swift: let array = [1,2,3]
let mydata = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(array,
                                                              options:0,
                                                              format: NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0, error: nil)

let myString = NSString(data: mydata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)